# How can i mix all of the arithmetical operators to finish my calculator

Tags: javascript, attributes, calculator

I had a calculator Project.I can multiply,add,divide and substract all the numbers in the input and get the result like output.
But i need help.How is the solution when the user
in same input wants first to substract,then divide then multiply and and etc. in this case.

A little explanation: I have the buttons with atribbutes and i added event listener when they are clicked they need to be showed on the screen.
After that i pushed them in array and then depen on the arithetic operation,*,/,+,- i make search with reg ex and after that i remove them and i make the operation a*b, a + b etc depending on that what includes the array when the = EQUAL BTN IS PRESSED. Can include *,/,+,- but in this case just one of that arithmetic operator.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const screen = document.querySelector(".screen");
const equalBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-equal")
const clearBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-clear")

let get = []

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let number = btns[i].getAttribute("data-num");
    screen.value += number;
    get.push(number);
    console.log(get);
  })
}


equalBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if (get.includes("*")) {
    const res = get.toString()
      .match(/[^*]+/g)
      .map(v => v.split(',')
        .filter(v => v)
        .map(v => +v))


    var Multiply = res.map(function(el) {
      return el.join('');
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a * b;
    });

    screen.value = Multiply;
  }


  if (get.includes("/")) {
    const res = get.toString()
      .match(/[^/]+/g)
      .map(v => v.split(',')
        .filter(v => v)
        .map(v => +v))


    var Divide = res.map(function(el) {
      return el.join('');
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a / b;
    });

    screen.value = Divide;
  }

  if (get.includes("+")) {
    const res = get.toString()
      .match(/[^+]+/g)
      .map(v => v.split(',')
        .filter(v => v)
        .map(v => +v))


    var Adding = res.map(function(el) {
      return el.join('');
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    });

    screen.value = Adding;
  }


  if (get.includes("-")) {
    const res = get.toString()
      .match(/[^-]+/g)
      .map(v => v.split(',')
        .filter(v => v)
        .map(v => +v))


    var Substracting = res.map(function(el) {
      return el.join('');
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });

    screen.value = Substracting;
  }


});



clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  get.length = 0;
  screen.value = "";
});
```